# Redirect /home to home.php

Tags: redirect, pages, homepage

In my WP admin's "Pages" section is a page called "Home" with a URL of /home. This page's content gets called by my index.php file.

My problem is the /home page is coming up in search results, or someone could type in /home. Is it possible to redirect /home to index.php (or just "/")?

Comment: You simply don't have to do that. You can just select some page as your entry page (admin > settings), which will then be your index.php target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your index.php file back to normal, then set that home page as the front page instead. Then the /home will redirect to / as it should.

Comment: How do I set the home page as the front page?

Comment: Settings->Reading. Choose what Page you want to be the front page, and choose another Page where you want the blog/posts to display.